# Barcode in coloured parallel lines

Tags: color, print-design, barcodes

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barcode

Can the Barcode parallel lines be coloured lines viz Red, Green, Blue etc i.e. other than Black & White?

Can we use contrasting colours other than black & white?

https://learn.g2.com/color-contrast

If No, Why?

Can there be technical challenges in designing & manufacturing a
Universal Colour  Barcode reader / scanner device?

Comment: For the actual question: Presumably the main reason to choose black and white is to have maximal contrast between what is and isn't a black bar.

Comment: Thanks. You mean contrasting colours. https://learn.g2.com/color-contrast

Comment: A barcode reader does not see the world the way you do. So just because you see it. The barcode reader may not.

Comment: Thanks. A coloured barcode reader cannot be designed & constructed similar to a colour scanner device?

Comment: It probably could - but why go to all that trouble just so you can use non-standard bar codes? A standard exists, it's black on white. There would probably be prismatic effects too - a lot of barcode readers work in a kind of pseudo-3D vision, so you can wave your product vaguely in the direction of the pair of spinning mirrors & be read in 3D space.

Comment: @Scott  - why did you delete your answer? I think it's still relevant. Although using coloured barcodes may indeed be possible, I think your general advice NOT to use them is still good.  Why mess with something that definitely works, and why risk potential scanning problems especially at a time like this when speed through the checkout is desirable? Pretty sure shop owners have enough problems to deal with these days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## **No**.

NOT a good idea.

Have you *ever* seen a colored barcode? Even one that's a single color other than black?

There is a very important *reason* all barcodes are black on white. They aren't even black on top of a color most of the time and include a surrounding white background area.

Barcodes need to be *read by scanners*. By altering the value of the stripes (or the background color) you could very well alter how the code is read entirely.

Every scanner may not be the same... What if one scanner has trouble picking up green and those lines get read as narrower than they are. Or skipped entirely?.. but another scanner overcompensates for green, thickening those lines as it's scanned, changing the product it *thinks* is being scanned?... it's rife with pitfalls.

**It is *not wise* to set a barcode in *anything* other than black with a white background.**

For some things **function** is far, far more important than form.

---

According to comments....

Apparently *some* colors are okay. Although I wonder if that's more a European aspect as opposed to a US aspect. In the US, I can't ever recall seeing a colored bar code. But perhaps in European/Asian countries it's okay. I honestly don't know about international aspects. All I know is in the US.. use black.

Comment: Well you can use some colors like brown on yellow or black on red works also and is used a lot. But not black on greens and blues, because red laser scanners cant see them. You always risk having problems though, and certainly do not use colors that halftone.

Comment: Actually all color is unadvisable. Color *may* work for one scanner.. but not *every* scanner.

Comment: brown and blue on yellow is pretty common in my local stores. Tried to read one with 12 different scanbers no problem.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen.  In 50+ years I've never seen a non-black/white barcode.

Comment: Ok ill dig up my lab report on this to see if i can find them. But apparently one vendor has changed their strategy since then citing slightly elevated unreliability. So its not like i disagree on the color.

Comment: I have one 6 hours ago in a food shop purchased plastic bag just now in my hands. It has blue product code on yellow background. My own handheld barcode scanner which has red LED light beam and a camera recognized the code perfectly one minute ago. In the shop the scanner of the self-cashing terminal didn't see it but a handheld scanner which was the 2nd scanner option of the terminal did read it. Different scanners use different light and maybe cannot see all color combinations . I guess red barcode on white cannot be red with red light. Color aware scanner isn't impossible but it costs more.

Comment: (Continued) The eye of the self-cashing terminal in the shop can also be programmed to ignore the bag because the customer handles it in front of the terminal. That's done to avoid multiple billing.

Comment: I've made a few blue (Pantone 072) barcodes (and a few other dark colors I think). Otherwise we would have to add a black ink just for the barcode. Never had any complaints. Here is a link to a [random page about barcode colors](https://www.barcode.graphics/upc-color/). Don't know that site really, but many sites tell the same story. (But I generally agree with the "better safe than sorry" strategy.)

Comment: Well shut the front door.. deleting my answer then :) Thanks @Wolff  -- I'm thinking this *may* be a European thing... because in the US.. I can't ever recall seeing anything other than black. ... and well.. I think all of you are non-US (guessing).

Comment: Okay.. undeleted @BillyKerr I simply didn't want to spread misinformation

Comment: @user287001 S marketin kassi?

Comment: @joojaa that's a right guess.

Comment: I’ve made barcodes in various colours as well (and quite frequently white on brown/black) for book covers, and my experience rather confirms Scott’s guess: I’ve never heard of it causing any problems in Europe, but our American distributors have complained several times of barcodes not being readable, even though all the scanners we used to test them had no problems at all.

Comment: I *have* seen white on black. But that's really the only variation in my experience.

Comment: @Scott - I have seen some coloured barcodes before, but by far the vast majority here in the UK are also black ink on a white background. It might also depend on where you shop or what brands you buy. Some discount supermarket own-brands might have cheaper packaging, perhaps just two colour printing to save on costs.

Comment: It's important to note that even here in chaotic and lawless Europe where *some* colors can be used for barcodes, it should *only* be done when printing with a spot color. Barcodes should *never* contain multiple inks and/or halftone screening.

Answer (score 3):

In most cases a multicolor barcode is a bad idea.

1. If your barcode is to be reproduced by offset, flexography or gravure printing, there is always some amount of random misregistration between the different colors. A multicolor barcode would be hyper sensitive for that.
2. Barcodes scanners need sufficient contrast and are often based on red lasers (that is why blue-on-white, green-on-white, black-on-pink or polished-metal on white is sometimes acceptable. But red on white would be invisible for such a scanner.
3. Just being-readable-by-the-majority-of-scanners is often not good enough. Many retailers set their own rules and/or require a minimum readability-score from a quality control scanner.

Actually, there exist special barcode types that are multicolor by design and always read by RGB cameras. But I assume you refer to more common barcodes, such as EAN-13.